# Join vs subquery to count nested objects

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Let's say my model contains 2 tables: persons and addresses. One person can have O, 1 or more addresses. I'm trying to execute a query that lists all persons and includes the number of addresses they have respectively. Here is the 2 queries that I have to achieve that:

```
SELECT
  persons.*,
  count(addresses.id) AS number_of_addresses
FROM `persons`
  LEFT JOIN addresses ON persons.id = addresses.person_id
GROUP BY persons.id
```

and

```
SELECT
  persons.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM addresses
   WHERE addresses.person_id = persons.id) AS number_of_addresses
FROM `persons`
```

And I was wondering if one is better than the other in term of performance.

Comment: What is this `cube_models` table, and why does it only appear in the second query?  The second query uses a correlated subquery, which in general tend to run slower than similar queries which use joins.

Comment: I believe the first one will be faster, but they are very similar. Just run an execution plan on both and see the differences. I doubt there is any better way of doing it .

Comment: I fixed the cube_models, bad copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

The way to determine performance characteristics is to actually run the queries and see which is better.

If you have no indexes, then the first is probably better.  If you have an index on `addresses(person_id)`, then the second is probably better.

The reason is a little complicated.  The basic reason is that `group by` (in MySQL) uses a sort.  And, sorts are O(n * log(n)) in complexity.  So, the time to do a sort grows faster than a data (not much faster, but a bit fast).  The consequence is that a bunch of aggregations for each person is faster than one aggregation by person over all the data.

That is conceptual.  In fact, MySQL will use the index for the correlated subquery, so it is often faster than the overall `group by`, which does not make use of an index.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first query is optimum and more optimization can provided by changing table structure. For example define both person_id and address_id fields (order is important) as primary key in addresses table to join faster.

The mysql table storage structure is indexed organized table(clustered index) so the primary key index is very faster than normal index specially in join operation.

Comment: `persons.id`, `addresses.id` and `addresses.person_id` all have index

Comment: @TrexXx , The mysql table storage structure is indexed organized table(clustered) so the primary key index is very faster than normal index specially in join operation.